# Pick up different values in 1 table

Tags: oracle, coldfusion

This is the example of my database table:

id -- pen color -- pen type -- pen price -- date purchased

1  -- red   -- type A   -- 10.00     -- 10/02/2013

1  -- white -- type B   -- 21.00     -- 13/02/2013

2  -- blue  -- type A   -- 12.00     -- 09/02/2013

1  -- yellow    -- type C   -- 14.00     -- 23/02/2013

My desired output is:

how about if i want it to be grouped by the same id?

id -- price A -- price A + B -- price B -- price C

1  -- 10.00   -- 31.00       -- 21.00   -- 14.00

2  -- 12.00   -- 0           -- 0       -- 0

I am seriously having a problem doing this. I think it might be simple, but I am just running out of ideas.

Comment: The question is not clear.   I understand your table structure but I can't figure out what you want to achieve.

Comment: @DanBracuk I was just typing the same thing.

Comment: hey i'm sorry. my desired output would be in a table.

the same id, with different types of pen. but i want to extract the price.

example: price for pen type A and price for type A + price for type B

is it clear? or am i making you even more confuse? T__T

Comment: What does ID signify? It's not really an ID as far as I can see.

Comment: that is only example that i can think of. actually my table is slightly different. but i can't expose it for confidentiality purpose.

Comment: will you only have one type A, B and C per ID or will there be multiple A, B or C?

Comment: @MattBusche there will be multiple A, B and C.

Comment: @faz then how do you decide which one to display? Your question is too vague for a legitimate answer

Comment: @MattBusche there will be a date, where user can select the date they purchase those pens. they wanted the output to be in a table, with the pen's type and price as well.

Comment: @faz you don't show a date anywhere in your question

Comment: opsie sorry. i left that part. @MattBusche
i edited the table already.

Comment: @DanBracuk i have edited my question. is it clear enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming only one id and type per date, this should work:

```
<cfquery name='b'>
SELECT ID
    , AVG( DECODE( Pen_Type, 'Type A', Pen_Price, 0 ) ) AS Price_A
    , AVG( DECODE( Pen_Type, 'Type B', Pen_Price, 0 ) ) AS Price_B
    , AVG( DECODE( Pen_Type, 'Type C', Pen_Price, 0 ) ) AS Price_C
FROM Pen_Table
WHERE Date_Purchase = #Date#
GROUP BY ID
</cfquery>
```

Note that the aggregate function of AVG can be any of the aggregate functions, it's only purpose is to get it to row one per id. This again only works assuming you only have one pen type per id, per date. If you have more rows, then this won't work. Given the information you've provided, I believe this will work. You can easily calculate A+B in the output, compared to trying to do it in the query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you Busches ! now i can see the flow. i can proceed to next steps yayyy. thanks munchkin :D

Answer (score 0):

While your exact needs are still unclear, the group attribute of cfoutput might put you on the right path.  In your case, try something like this.

```
 <cfquery name="yourquery">
 select blah, blah
 order by id
 </cfquery>
```

The order by id is important.  It leads to

```
<cfoutput query="yourquery" group ="id">
#grouped data#
<cfoutput>
#ungrouped data#
</cfoutput>
#more grouped data if you want#
</cfoutput>
```

That's the general idea.  You should be able to adapt it to your specific requirements.

Comment: That's how the group attribute works.  Time for you to play around with it.